# IIS loses HTTPS Endpoitn certificate after computer restart

Tags: iis, ssl, binding, endpoint

I know I am not the one who is losing a certificate association after computer restart.
In particular:

- Open "Site Bindind" dialog in IIS
- Find my HTTPS binding
- Press "Edit..."
- From the "SSL certificate" I am selecting my certifivate
- Press Apply

Everything works just perfect, but until the computer restarts.
After the restart when I open the Binding properties I see (Not selected)

what I have discovered that after

```
netsh http show sslcert
```

I cannot see my port I am using for HTTPS binding

when I am
netsh http add sslcert ipport=0.0.0.0:port certhash= appid={ID}

everything works further

As sa fast but dirty solution I have created a bat file with the following content:

```
netsh http del sslcert ipport=0.0.0.0:port
netsh http add sslcert ipport=0.0.0.0:port certhash=<Hash> appid={ID}
```

and scheduled launch of the bat file in Windows Scheduler (At start up after 1 minutes)
worked for some time, but now has stopped.

What is wrong at how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I just had a similar problem, where my SSL bindings for my self-hosted OWIN app were lost whenever I restarted the machine.

I came across this post: [Adding SSL Certificate via "netsh.exe" does not last after a machine restart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9710942/adding-ssl-certificate-via-netsh-exe-does-not-last-after-a-machine-restart), which mentions:

> I think by moving the self signed cert from Personal to Trusted Root CA directory causes a problem that SSL stops working after developers reboot their machines. (Don't know how it happens, but it does happen consistently.) I finally get around this issue by export and re-import the self-signed cert into the trusted root directory (instead of simply drag it over). Now my self-signed cert is considered and I don't need to REINSTALL/REPAIR IIS Express every time I reboot the machine.

My scenario was a bit different, but when I imported my localhost SSL cert, I was also using drag-n-drop to copy it from the Personal Certificates for "Current User" to the Personal Certificates for "Local Computer."  **So I deleted my cert and re-imported without using drag-n-drop, and that seems to have handled it - I can now reboot my machine without losing my SSL port bindings!**

Hopefully this will work for you as well (if you are still having the issue).

Answer (score 0):

I experienced a similar issue after reboots with my Windows Admin Center server, and I believe it is related. After many, *many* hours of progressive research and troubleshooting, I ended up simply using MMC's certlm.msc to import the certificate to Trusted Root Certification Authorities, then *copying* the certificate from Trusted Root Certification Authorities to Personal.

**This only worked for me under the following conditions**

- The certificate was exportable
- The certificate was imported for the **Local Machine**, not **Current User**, as this was for a **Windows Workgroup** environment.
- The certificate had a password-protected private key ( also because of Local Machine / Workgroup setup )

**EDIT**: The top answer by @jglouie on this post states something pretty similar. https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75859585/edit