# SSL certificate bindings for self-hosted ASP.NET Web API lost after reboot

Tags: c#, ssl, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, netsh

I'm working on a ASP.NET Web API project. The Web API is self-hosted using OWIN. The OWIN self-host runs as a Windows service. Most of the Web API's controllers require HTTPS, and I have a small configuration program for the Web API service that successfully creates a self-signed SSL certificate in the Local Machine store and binds it to the Web API's port using netsh. I can then successfully connect to the Web API over HTTPS. In short, everything works as expected ... until I reboot the machine.

After rebooting, even I have verified though both the certificate and the binding are still there, I can no longer access the service over HTTPS, getting only a 502 error. Fiddler, for example, reports:

```
HTTP/1.1 502 Fiddler - Connection Failed 
Date: Fri, 13 Feb 2015 09:27:28 GMT 
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8 
Connection: close 
Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate 
Timestamp: 10:27:28.571 

[Fiddler] The connection to 'host.example.com' failed. <br />  System.Security.SecurityException Failed to negotiate HTTPS connection with server.fiddler.network.https&gt; HTTPS handshake to host.example.com failed. System.IO.IOException Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. &lt; An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
```

It seems that the SSL binding is lost. I found some questions about similar problems such as [IIS loses HTTPS Endpoitn certificate after computer restart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27564823/iis-loses-https-endpoitn-certificate-after-computer-restart), but they're about IIS, which, to my knowledge, does not come into the picture at all in my case, as self-hosting a Web API uses WCF under the hood.

I'm currently completely out of ideas here, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question here for future reference and other poor souls running into similar issues ...

The problem was with how I created and stored the self-signed certificate. While my X509Certificate2 instance did contain the private key, it wasn't stored in the machine key set, but in the user key set, because I didn't specify the  X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet when creating the certificate in code. (See also [tips 2 and 3 in this blog entry](http://paulstovell.com/blog/x509certificate2) for more context.)
Using the "[FindPrivateKey](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa717039%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)" tool helped me finding this out.

Now I must admit that I don't fully understand why this ever worked in the first place (i.e. after the certificate was freshly created), but it's pretty clear why this didn't work after rebooting, as the self-hosted Web API, running as a Windows service as LocalSystem, couldn't find the private key.

(Note: all this time, the Management Console did tell me "You have a private key that corresponds to this certificate", which confused things further for me.)

Comment: I am struggling with getting this working but I think I am really close. I would like to chat with you directly about it if possible. Are you open to that?